# highlight menu on hover using css/javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to highlight (transparent color with border smaller than the image tab) my menu items using hover through javascript. But, I can't seem to get it right. As an dded effect, when the menu tab is clicked, I want to have a bouncing animation for my image tab. Can this be done?

Here's my javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("img").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <ul class="menu_tab">
 <li><a href="#"><img src="images/top_menu_tabs/kaiiki.jpg" alt="tab1" /></a>
 <div class="highlight"></div>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
 ul.menu-tab
 {
     z-index:0;
     list-style:none;
     overflow:hidden;
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
 }
 ul.menu-tab li
 {
     display:block;
     color:#ffffff;
     margin-right:0px;
     margin-bottom:0px;
     position:relative;
     overflow:hidden;
     cursor:pointer;
 }
 ul.menu-tab a
 {
     display:block;
     width:60px;
     height:50px;
     overflow:hidden;
     border:0;
 }
 ul.menu-tab a:hover 
 {

     color:green;
     background-color:#ccffcc;
     margin-left:-20px;
     padding-left:20px;
     padding-right:20px;
     width:50px;
     border:20px solid green; 
 }
 .highlight
    {
     color:Green;
     width:auto;
     width:auto;
     padding:0;
  }
```

The image I want to achieve is something like this: http://www4.kaiho.mlit.go.jp/CeisNetWebGIS/

Comment: Where is the relevant code and what have you already tried?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more examples [brainjar](http://www.brainjar.com/css/tabs/demo.html)                                                    Demo More from [Brainjar](http://www.brainjar.com/css/tabs/)